# org-mode links to gnus articles with imap

Tags: org-mode, gnus, hyperlinks, imap

When using gnus with nnimap (IMAP access to a remote mail server) and linking gnus articles (e-mail messages) in org-mode files.

**What** are the **pros** and **cons** of gnus **storage methods** (for articles) in regard  of having **reliable** access to articles, when there is **no network** connection (aka: offline mode)?

As I see there are multiple possibilities to store a gnus article on local hard disk and I can't see the implications or drawbacks of those methods.

- [article caching](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Article-Caching.html)
- [persistent article](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Persistent-Articles.html#Persistent-Articles)
- [article archiving](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Archived-Messages.html)
- [article saving](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Saving-Articles.html)
- using a [separate directory](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Directory-Groups.html#Directory-Groups) or [separate backend](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Choosing-a-Mail-Back-End.html#Choosing-a-Mail-Back-End) (like nnml) and copy articles to this

*Note:* I do not care about storage or inodes usage on my local hard disk.
I do not want to use `important mark` for all articles.
I speak about e-mails only (no news involved, yet)

Comment: I use *offlineimap* so all imap mail saved locally. Org can link directly to the message in gnus; available on or offline.

Comment: @JeffreyDeLeo, thanks for your comment. I tested with `mbsync` because I read it should be superior to `offlineimap`. Here I'm not really happy with external mail fetching (either periodic or via an self written elisp function), and its synchronization back to the imap server.

Comment: One thing I do with mail is copy or move it to a *nnfolder* group, which is stored locally. For news groups, I use article caching often to save things.